# How can I create a new dataframe column by creating a list from the existing one?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column where each row is a string and looks something like this:

> a&bc,123,#ahd

I want to convert it into a comma separated list that looks like this:

> ['a&bc', '123', '#ahd']

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Comment: `df['numtech'] = df.groupby(['emp','quarter']).transform('count')` for your previous question =)

Comment: That isn't counting the number of technologies